# PersistentVector cannot be cast to class IAtom

Tags: clojure

I have a local variable that I must store some texts as a list/vector.

I want to add values to these vector according to some conditions, so what I wanna do is just add values to the vector and in the end have a updated version of this vector

But when I try to use the !swap I always get an error.

I've tried these two options:

```
(do
  (let
    [error-list ()]
    (println (conj error-list "test"))
    (swap! error-list conj "test2")))
```

**The result:**
(test)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class **clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IAtom** (clojure.lang.PersistentVector and clojure.lang.IAtom are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

And:

```
(do
  (let
    [error-list []]
    (println (conj error-list "test"))
    (swap! error-list conj "test2")))
```

**The result:**
[test]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class **clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IAtom** (clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList and clojure.lang.IAtom are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a local variable, that is a let binding. You have bound the name error-list to the value '() in the first snippet and [] in the second.

`swap!` is a function for updating the value of an atom. You do not have an atom, you have (first snippet) a List and (2nd snippet) a Vector. You can wrap either of these in an Atom to allow for mutable state using the `atom` function.

```
(do
  (let
    [error-list (atom [])]
    (println (swap! error-list conj "test"))
    (swap! error-list conj "test2")
    @error-list))
[test]
["test" "test2"]
user=>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to use atom but as (atom ()), and the conj didn't work, so I thought the mistake was in the atom. Thank you for the correction in the naming, I'm new in functional programming so, I'm still a little confused about the names

Comment: I'm surprised it didn't work. emptylist certainly supports conj. `(conj (conj () "test2") "test3") => ("test3" "test2")` As a person who's new to functional programming I'd recommend you avoid using atoms or other mutable state as much as possible so you get used to it. Also StackOverflow is great for very specific quetions, but if you're looking for more general advice and help on learning clojure and functional programming I would join the clojurians slack community.